# SQL - How to count number of distinct values (payments), after sum of rows where they have another column value (Due Date) in common

Tags: sql, count, sum, partition

My 'deals_payments' table is:

```
Due Date    Payment     ID
1-Mar-19    1,000.00    123
1-Apr-19    1,000.00    123
1-May-19    1,000.00    123
1-Jun-19    1,000.00    123
1-Jul-19    1,000.00    123
1-Aug-19    1,000.00    123
1-Jun-19    500.00      456
1-Jul-19    500.00      456
1-Aug-19    500.00      456
```

I have the SQL code:

```
select 
   count(*), payment

from (select deals_payments.*,
             (row_number() over (order by due_date) -
              row_number() over (partition by payment order by due_date)
             ) as grp
      from deals_payments
       where id = 123
           ) deals_payments
group by grp, payment
order by grp
```

which gives me what I want - the number of payments on each distinct amount - (here I only asked for ID 123):

```
COUNT(*)    PAYMENT
6           1000.00
```

But now I need the sum of payments of the two ID's (123 and 456), where the due dates are the same, and count the number of payments on each distinct amount, as:

```
COUNT(*)    PAYMENT
3           1000.00
3           1500.00
```

I tried the below but it gives me the 'missing right parenthesis' error. What is wrong??

```
    select 
      count(*), 
      (select 
          sum(total) total
       from (select distinct 
                due_date,
                (select 
                   sum(payment) 
                from deals_payments 
                where  (due_date = a.due_date)) as total
             from deals_payments a 
             where a.id in (123, 456) 
             and payment > 0)

        group by due_date
        order by due_date)  b

    from (select deals_payments.*,
                     (row_number() over (order by due_date) -
                              row_number() over (partition by payment order by due_date)
                             ) as grp
                      from deals_payments
                       where id = 123
                           ) deals_payments
                group by grp, payment
                order by grp
```

Comment: Your sample data shows 1000.00 and 1500.00.  How are these calculated?

Comment: based on the Due Dates. see my table at the top of the post - it has payments in Jun, Jul and Aug that appear in both IDs 123 and 456, so the sum of 1500.

Comment: . . Both ids have payments in those months.  Why is the other not 3000.00?

Comment: I dont want the sum of payments with the same ID, I want the sum of ID 123 + ID 456, where the due dates are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your earlier comments into consideration, I agree that the SQL can be simplified to get the intended result. My understanding is that the expected output is the frequency of the total payment of a subset of IDs on any given date.

```
select count(*) as PaymentFrequency, TotalPaidOnDueDate from
(
    select due_date, sum(payment) as TotalPaidOnDueDate from #deals_payments
    where ID in (123, 456)
    group by due_date
) a
group by a.TotalPaidOnDueDate
```

Here is a sql fiddle I used to verify: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b04f/1

Comment: holy mother! ...that's it, worked as expected and is way simpler! Thank you @sjager !

Answer (score 0):

This seems really strange.  I don't understand why your logic is so complicated.

How about this?

```
select id, count(*), max(payment)
from (select dp.*,
             count(*) over (partition by due_date) as cnt
      from deal_payments dp
      where dp.id in (123, 456)
     ) dp
where cnt = 2
group by id;
```

Comment: thanks, but with this one I'm getting the Count with Due Date in common between the two distinct payments (3 of 500.00 and 3 of 1000.00). I need to sum the payments and then count with Due Dates in common, so would show 3 of 500.00 and 3 of 1500.00

Comment: @Solera . . . You can use `sum()` instead of `max()`.  Your sample data is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. Could this do the trick???

```
select payment, count(*)
  from deals_payments 
 where due_date in 
(select due_date
  from deals_payments
  group by due_date
  having count(*) > 1)
 group by payment;
```

You can add a filter by id if you want, of course.